# How to navigate from one page to hubsection on another page?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have two pages in my application: "HubPage" and "SectionPage".
How can I navigate from SectionPage to a given Hubsection programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

Navigate with hub index as parameter

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(HubPage), 1)
```

In your hub page:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var index = (int)e.Parameter;
    switch (index)
    {
        case 0: YourHub.ScrollToSection(Hub1);break;
        case 1: YourHub.ScrollToSection(Hub2);break;
    }
}
```